# undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to remove from a  text box anything that is not between `[]`. This works for `edit` record form:

```
<%= f.text_field :transport_relay, :value => f.object.transport_relay.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]  %>
```

but when I try to create a `new` record, it displays `` "undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass" `` error as expected, as the new record has noting to match with. How do I handle this problem?

I tried several solutions, i.e., this:

```
<%= f.text_field :transport_relay, :value => f.object.transport_relay.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]  if f.object.transport_relay %>
```

solved the error problem, but also removed the input text box in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `if` to apply only to the :value argument, not the entire f.text_field. Put () around the :value value

```
 <%= f.text_field :transport_relay, :value => (f.object.transport_relay.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]  if f.object.transport_relay) %>
```

Comment: That worked for me like a charm :). Thank you all for your input and time spent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is good [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/andand) called **andand gem** to handle this problem ("undefined method `any_method' for nil:NilClass").

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like

```
<%= f.text_field :transport_relay, :value => f.object.transport_relay.nil? ? nil:f.object.transport_relay.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]  %>
```

but I think it would be better if you extracted that logic to your model

```
def transport_relay_value
  transport_relay.nil? nil:transport_relay.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]
end

<%= f.text_field :transport_relay, :value => f.object.transport_relay_value  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `def nil.match; nil end`